# Semantic Error using Conditionals statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a code which executes the length of a string

This code should be able to accept only Strings and return their length but when integer or float values are given, it counts their length too.

```
def length(string):
    if type(string)== int:
        return "Not Available"
    elif type(string) == float:
        return "Not Allowed"
    else:
        return len(string)
string=input("Enter a string: ")
print(length(string))
```

Output:

```
Enter a string: 45
2
```

Comment: The string will be a string, no matter what symbols it contains. It will not be an int or a float, no matter how much it looks like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect to get output `'Not Available'` for the input `45`. But it won't happen because,
while reading input from keyboard default type is string. Hence, the input `45` is of type `str`. Therefore your code gives output `2`.

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string so if you check its type it will always be string. To check if its an int or a float you have to try to cast it.

```
try:
    int(input)
except ValueError:
    # not an int
    return "Not Available"

try:
   float(input)
except ValueError:
    # not a float
    return "Not Allowed"

return len(string)
```